# Angular CLI 6 - Build Angular Libraries With Source Maps

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I've got an Angular 6 project that I've generated using Angular CLI 6 (6.08).

I created separate libraries using the `ng generate library [lib name] --prefix [lib prefix]` (approach outlined in this article: https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11).

I build each library using `ng build [lib name]` and then serve my application using `ng serve`.

However, when I view the source in Chrome Dev Tools, my libraries don't have source maps.

I've tried building each library using `ng build [lib name] --source-map` (as specified here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build), but I think that's only for building that application, not libraries.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong have an alternative solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50775520/606662

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view the source code of the angular library in the consuming app.
We need to do the following 2 points:

1. Enable source maps when when building the angular library.
2. Enable source maps + vendorSourceMap when building the consuming app.

To enable source maps when when building the angular library.

1. In `angular.json` under, projects -> library_name -> architect -> build -> options
2. Enable source maps:

   ```json
   "sourceMap": {
     "scripts": true,
     "styles": true,
     "vendor": true
   }
   ```

To enable source maps + vendorSourceMap when building the consuming app.

1. In `angular.json` under, projects -> projctName -> architect -> build
2. Set `sourceMap` to `true`:

   ```json
   "sourceMap": true
   ```
3. In `angular.json` under projects -> projctName -> serve -> options
4. Set `vendorSourceMap` to `true`:

   ```json
   "vendorSourceMap": true
   ```

Finally run the consuming app using the command:

```sh
ng serve --vendor-source-map
```

Comment: vendorSourceMap seems to be no longer available in ng11

Comment: There is no sourceMap property under projects -> library_name -> architect -> build -> options. I'm using ng11.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I ended up with pointing the library path directly to the `public_api.ts` file of the library instead of to the `dist` folder. This way I'm able to debug the application in the Dev Tools without any problems (furthermore I'm able to debug it directly from within Visual Studio Code this way).

So in your `tsconfig.json` instead of this:

```
"paths": {
  "my-lib": [
    "dist/my-lib"
  ]
}
```

I replaced it with this:

```
"paths": {
  "my-lib": [
    "projects/my-lib/src/public_api.ts"
  ]
}
```

This also has the nice side effect that auto reload works when doing changes in the library code.

However I'm not sure if it is recommended to do it that way, so I would like to see other approaches.

Comment: This is a great workaround. Please update this thread if Angular publishes a recommended approach if different than what you've done.

Comment: It's also like you need an `angular-dev.json` that the CLI uses unless you specify the `prod` argument.

Answer (score 8):

In your angular.json you can add "vendorSourceMap: true" to enable sourcemaps from your libraries to work.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "vendorSourceMap": true
```

Comment: Seems to work, but will the source maps be left for a production build?

Comment: Also, although this produces the source maps, they don't appear to be used when the `ng server` command is run for the entire solution

Comment: This gives me the following error: `Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(vendorSourceMap).` in v7.3.8

Comment: Running `ng serve --vendor-source-map` is working for me on ng-cli v7.38 without the build config change above.

Comment: Like @TheMagnificent11 said, the sourcemaps won't come up when using the `ng serve` command. To see the sourcemaps with `ng serve`, add the option at projects -> your-app -> architect -> serve -> options -> vendorSourceMap

Comment: This answer no longer works - the `"sourceMap": { "vendor": true }` in the accepted answer is the way to go.

Comment: `ng serve --vendor-source-map` is not working for `Angular CLI: 13.3.10`.

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 9+ setting the sourceMap for the local dev configuration of the app in **angular.json**

```
    "sourceMap": {
       "scripts": true,
       "styles": true,
       "vendor": true
      },
```

works without any other changes.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56669585/403999 is a bit more detailed. It is not required or allowed to enable Source Maps when building the library just enable Source Maps when consuming the library.