# How to make Angular watch multiple libraries for changes and recompile when needed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-scripts, angular-library

This question is much the same as [Make angular app watch for libraries changes and update itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473727/make-angular-app-watch-for-libraries-changes-and-update-itself). But, that question was never successfully answered as applies to the use of multiple libraries. I also reviewed [Angular library and live reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356732/angular-library-and-live-reload/59706221#59706221) and surveyed the answers and links from both questions.

My app is using two libraries: `lib-1` and `lib-2`. When those files are edited, they are ignored and the app does not recompile. To see changes, I have to restart the server which really slows things down.

My expectation is that the app should be recompile when library files are edited, just like when other app-internal files are edited.

This is an Angular project that I have inherited, and the original author is no longer available. I am using Angular v10 and npm 6.14.11

The initial npm scripts are:

```
"start:staging": "ng serve --configuration-staging --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disableHostCheck",
"build:lib-1": "ng build lib-1 && cpx projects/lib-1/src/lib/theme.scss dist/lib-1",
"build:lib-2": "ng build lib-2 && cpx projects/lib-2/src/lib/theme.scss dist/lib-2",
"build:libs": "npm run build:lib-1 && npm run build:lib-2",
```

With those, I first run `npm run build:libs`, then `npm run start:staging`. As mentioned, this does not "watch" my libraries for changes.

I reviewed the suggestions and the other SO questions (above), have ensured that the `npm-run-all`, `wait-on` and `rimraf` libraries are now installed.

I have written these new npm scripts:

```
"clean": "rimraf dist",
"start-app": "wait-on dist/lib-1/fesm2015 dist/lib-2/fesm2015 && start:staging --poll 2000",
"watch:lib-1": "npm run build:lib-1 --watch",
"watch:lib-2": "npm run build:lib-2 --watch",
"watch-libs": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:lib-1 watch:lib-2",
"watch-all": "npm-run-all clean --parallel watch-libs start-app"
```

And, I am using the pre-existing `start:staging` script, as written.

I run `npm run watch-all`.

The script runs and proceeds to the point of building the libraries in parallel (bad idea?), and then throws error: `sh: start:staging: command not found`.

I removed the `--parallel` switches and tried again, and got the same error.

The `start:staging` script is indeed in the scripts object, and I cannot figure out why it's not being found.

I'm hoping to get some sage advice on correcting my syntax so that the app will compile and watch my library files along with the other files that are inside the app's `src` folder.

Comment: have you looked at nrlw's [nx workspace](https://nx.dev/). it offers a number of benefits above vanilla angular. one of them is the type of reloading you are looking for

Comment: It seems like to use the nx workspace, I'd need to create a new app and start over...? not an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of sleuthing, I came across [Nikola Kolev's Angular 6: build — watch multiple dependent libraries in one shell post](https://medium.com/@ntkolev/angular-6-build-watch-multiple-dependent-libraries-in-one-shell-562a5131788c).

While I don't have it down to one npm script like Nikola was able to do, I am able to do it by running two scripts (there are 7 total scripts involved), and that's good enough for now. I'll work on condensing to one when I get more time.

First, be sure to have [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on), [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) and [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) installed. We're also using [cpx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx); but, that's not about getting the libraries to be "watched" -- just including to be overly thorough.

Here are all the scripts:

```
"clean": "rimraf dist",
"watch-lib:lib-1": "ng build lib-1 --watch",
"watch-lib:lib-2": "ng build lib-2 --watch",
"watch-libs": "npm-run-all clean --parallel watch-lib:*",
"copy-styles:lib-1": "cpx projects/lib-1/src/lib/theme.scss dist/lib-1",
"copy-styles:lib-2": "cpx projects/lib-2/src/lib/theme.scss dist/lib-2",
"start-staging": "ng serve --configuration-staging --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disableHostCheck",  
"watch-staging": "npm-run-all copy-styles:* start:staging"
```

When I want to work on the libraries and have them be "watched", I run `npm run watch-libs` in one terminal. When that is finished, I run `npm run watch:staging` in a second terminal. Then, I'm able to launch the app in a browser, and any edits to any of the code, in libraries or in the app itself are caught, and the app recompiles as desired.

Comment: There is another approach described at the [Angular-CLI Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10643#issuecomment-423935700). I haven't tried it yet, but plan to give it a go.

Comment: I've addressed the new approaches in an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71375807/392895).