# How to debug into Angular Core.js

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I have an Angular 9 based application, I tried to set a break point at  @angular/core library code to see some variable, basically the relevant code is in core.umd.js under @angular/core package.

```
function checkAndUpdateView(view) {
    ....
}
```

I used "ng serve" to launch the application in Chrome 87.0.4280.8, my application is in default debug mode. I can set the break point in my application component's code like app.component.ts file in Chrome Developer tools and see the execution stop at my break point. In core.js, although I can set the break point there, the execution did not stop there. Like the screenshot.

[image]

I also tried use `"ng serve --vendorSourceMap"` or add `"vendorSourceMap": true` in angular.json file as suggested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775520/how-do-you-debug-an-angular-6-library), but after that I can find the targeted function in view.ts, and once I put the break point there, it is still not be hit.

I want to know the correct way to debug into Angular 9+ library code.

Comment: Make sure "black box content scripts" is not turned on for scripts.

Comment: I checked it is not turned on.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your trying to investigate an `expression has changed after it was checked` error. You can probably check the call stack and click each (anonymous) call to dig deeper.